# load calibration parameters into camera_info

Tags: ros, calibration, realsense

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the Intel RealSense R200 for my vision based project. I have managed to run the [stereo calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration) for the infrared stream and I have also obtained the calibration data file (.yaml) for the left and right infrared stream.

Currently, I am subscribing to the raw left and right infrared stream (*'/camera/ir/image_raw' and '/camera/ir2/camera_info'*) from the default nodelet (*r200_nodelet_default.launch*)

I would like to know how do I load the calibration parameters that I have obtained into the respective camera_info topics namely (*'/camera/ir/camera_info' and '/camera/ir2/camera_info'*) so I can run the [stereo_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc) to obtain the rectified infrared stream.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248356/load-calibration-parameters-into-camera_info/) by [timku](https://answers.ros.org/users/28140/timku/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear timku,

the standard way is to use the camera_info_manager ([wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_info_manager)).

BTW I'm quite confused by your goal: the Intel RealSense R200 manage the stereo vision by itself and its [node](http://wiki.ros.org/realsense_camera) provide the disparity map, depth point cloud and camera_info. So you don't need to calibrate it: this is a task for the camera itself.

Greetings
Alessandro

---

Originally posted by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) with karma: 497 on 2016-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [timku](https://answers.ros.org/users/28140/timku/) on 2016-11-18**:
Hi Alessandro,

Do you have any example of using the camera_info_manager as I can't seem to find any example online. Do you mean that the camera is factory calibrated?

**Comment by [timku](https://answers.ros.org/users/28140/timku/) on 2016-11-18**:
And I have managed to sync the left and right IR stream topic and would like to generate the disparity map through [stereo_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc). However, the disparity window freeze after using the image_view disparity view method. Is this the proper method?

**Comment by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) on 2016-11-18**:
The stereo_image_proc node is designed to elaborate two images taken at same time from two different and separated camera (like two webcam) in order to create a disparity map and 3D point cloud.

The RealSense R200 instead is a stereo camera and produce those info by itself.

**Comment by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) on 2016-11-18**:
This means that the algorithm provided in stereo_image_proc is INSIDE the RealSense. Look at the topic published by the realsense_camera node:
depth/camera_info (sensor_msgs/CameraInfo)
depth/image_raw (sensor_msgs/Image) - basically the disparity map
depth/points (sensor_msgs/PointCloud2)

**Comment by [timku](https://answers.ros.org/users/28140/timku/) on 2016-11-18**:
Ok, thanks for the above infor! That clearly clarify some of my doubts on the Realsense camera!

**Comment by [timku](https://answers.ros.org/users/28140/timku/) on 2016-11-18**:
Btw, I am working on my final year project (vision-based obstacle detection in GPS-denied outdoor environment) using the RealSense R200 through selecting appropriate stereo detector and stereo matching algorithms. After which, I will generate the disparity/depth map to detect any nearby obstacle.

**Comment by [timku](https://answers.ros.org/users/28140/timku/) on 2016-11-18**:
Just to check is there any feature detector function and stereo matching algorithms that is inside the ROS package? Or I can just use the OpenCV library in ROS?

**Comment by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) on 2016-11-18**:
I guess this is a task for the Point Could Library. As OpenCV also PCL has a porting in ROS: see its [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl) page. More info about PCL [here](http://pointclouds.org).